# Android 3 Scrollviews for comparing

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app that can compare three things at once. Normally they can be opened one at a time and loaded into a scrollview. How would I place 3 scrollviews on the same screen, that each take up exactly 1/3 of the screen, so that a profile could be loaded into each one and all 3 would be scrollable. I think this would make for a pretty nifty comparing layout.

Thoughts?

So basically, the whole activity wouldn't scroll, but would contain 3 small scrollviews that could be each individually scrolled.

[Activity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3NEn.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:weightSum`
Like This

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />
     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How would I make them stack on top of each other?

Comment: can use Image to share how you want it to be and if this solves ur previous issue please select this answer

Comment: android:orientation="vertical" change to this

Comment: please select the answer